# c# use query result as index in table

Tags: c#, linq

I have this table:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
```

And this query:

```
var result = (from i in dc.Ses
                      where i.id == id
                      select
                        new
                        {
                            id = i.id,
                            FullName = i.FullName,
                            Type = i.Type
                        }).ToList();
```

But I want to alter the `result` so `Type` will contain this `arr1[i.Type]`. 
Because `i.Type` is nullable if `i.Type == null` then `Type = null` also

Comment: Notice, If `i.Type` isn't a number and not in range you will get an exception. What is the issue of changing that line ?

Comment: it is a number and it is in range. but its nullable

Comment: Just use, `i.Type.Value` or `i.Type.GetValueOrDefault(SomeDefaultNumberHere)`and make sure you handle the case of a nullable with default.

Comment: can you provide your answer with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Type = i.Type.HasValue ? arr1[i.Type] : null
```

---

EDIT to split the query

```
var partialResult = (from i in dc.Ses
                      where i.id == id
                      select
                        new
                        {
                            id = i.id,
                            FullName = i.FullName,
                            RawType = i.Type
                        });

var finalResult = partialResult.AsEnumerable().Select(entry => new {
    ...
    Type = entry.RawType.HasValue ? arr1[entry.RawType] : null
});
```

Comment: I get this error: Unrecognized expression node: ArrayIndex

Comment: thats because i assume type is a string and the index expects an int. in other words if type == "three" then you want arr1[2] not arr1["three"]

Comment: @Muckeypuck no i.Type is int

Comment: That's probably happening because the query is "complex" to be translated to sql. You should split que query in 2 parts. Let me update my answer

Comment: Small nitpick: no need for the `ToList` in the first query. the `AsEnumerable()` should convert the rest of the query to linq-to-objects.

Comment: You're right. Edited the answer with that and added the "entry." before the "RawType"